# Android Image Processing,Pixel colors and shades

Tags: android, bitmap

I am working a color pallet application where i have to generate different shades of a color and convert the same into some other color and its shades.
This is code to get all pixels from a bitmap.

Here mImage is my bitmap.

```
        int width = mImage.getWidth();
        int height = mImage.getHeight();
        int[] pixels = new int[width * height];
        mImage.getPixels(pixels, 0, width, 0, 0, width, height);
```

You can further see this links that possibly tell you on how to generate shades.

Problem : i am getting all colors in integer values like -34454323 .
And i am very much confused about how to find that given integer code is shade of some pure color or itself a pure color.

Another question: Is there any direct method to change the hue and saturation property of a pixel to some targeted pixel.

Like converting a dark blue pixel to light red pixel.

Answer (score 0):

you can use BitmapShader, here is a nice tutorial about it from Romain Guy
http://www.curious-creature.org/2012/12/13/android-recipe-2-fun-with-shaders/

Comment: thanks for your link,but Bitmapshader is all about to change brightness of a pixel,where my question is really targeting Hue and Saturation of colors and their shades.

Comment: it's not all about brightness, only the tutorial is about brightness, with bitmap shader you can also change hue and saturation, you can also set them via matrixes too, take a look at this snippet
ColorMatrix colorizerMatrix = new ColorMatrix();
    colorizerMatrix.setSaturation(value);
    ColorMatrixColorFilter colorizerFilter = new ColorMatrixColorFilter(colorizerMatrix);
    mBitmapDrawable.setColorFilter(colorizerFilter);

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're getting such strange errors is because getPixels returns and array "packed ints" - each one representing a [Color](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html) object (see full docs [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#getPixels%28int%5B%5D,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29)).  Each 8-bits of the int are B,G,R color respectively.

If you want the exact values for RGB of a pixel you will need to do something like

```
// code untested
int R = (intcolor >> 16) & 0xff;
int G = (intcolor >> 8) & 0xff;
int B = intcolor & 0xff;
```

Comment: i can directly get RGB values by these methods 
                int redValue = Color.red(pixel);
  int blueValue = Color.blue(pixel);
  int greenValue = Color.green(pixel);

the question is,i really want to get one of the nearest pure color of the pixel.For example if pixel is some variation of pure yellow than how would i know that it is variation of yellow color.